# Robotframework:How to replace parts of regex matches strings

Tags: regex, robotframework

I use robot framework at following environment.

- Python 2.7.6
- robotframework 2.8.7
- Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

I want to remove " charactor from strings if matches "[0-9]*" pattern.
My code is follwing but this cannot work unknown parameter.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Collections
Library    json
Library    String

*** Variables ***
${TARGET_STRING}   {"host": "['192.168.1.2', '192.168.1.3']", "part": "['ZZZ1', 'ZZZ2']", "name": "XXXX", "kara": null, "type": "123", "id": "YYYY", "flg": false,"type2": "4567","type3": "4"}


*** Test Cases ***
My Test Case
    ${resp}    My Keyword    ${TARGET_STRING}

*** Keywords ***
My Keyword
    [Arguments]    ${string}
    ${resp}    Replace String Using Regexp    ${string}    "[0-9][0-9][0-9]"   123
    ${resp}    Replace String Using Regexp    ${resp}    "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"   4567
    ${resp}    Replace String Using Regexp    ${resp}    "[0-9]"   4
    Log To Console    ${resp}
```

output

```
 {"host": "['192.168.1.2', '192.168.1.3']", "part": "['ZZZ1', 'ZZZ2']", "name": "XXXX", "kara": null, "type": 123, "id": "YYYY", "flg": false,"type2": 4567,"type3": 4}
```

(In this case , I want to change
"type": "123" to "type": 123,
"type2": "4567" to "type2": 4567,
"type3": "4" to "type3": 4 and not to change others)

How can I generalize it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
"[^"]+"\s*:\s*)"([0-9]+)"
```

The Python for that might look something like:

```
p = re.compile(ur'("[^"]+"\s*:\s*)"([0-9]+)"', re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
```

The replacement string will be: `\1\2`, which may need to be escaped as `\\1\\2`. This will effectively recombine the two parts without the quotes around the number.

Comment: The replacement string should be `\\1\\2` - the $ syntax doesn't get recognized in RF.